# Covariance and Correlation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, correlation

Suppose there were *m* married couples, but *d* of these *2m* people have died. Regard the *d* deaths as striking the *2m* people at random. Let X be the number of surviving couples.

Find:

a) E(X)

b) Var(X)

For part (a) I got E(X)=m((2m-d)/2m)^2  but im not sure how to calculate the variance.

Comment: The question might become interesting if you include how you got E(X).

Comment: I found the prob of a single person surviving to be: (2m-d)/d. I took this probability and squared it to find the prob of a couple surviving to be: [(2m-d)/d]^2. Then I multiplied this probability by the number of couples m, to get the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a person survives is $1-\frac{d}{2m}$. Conditionally on the event that his person survives, the probability that a second person survives is $1-\frac{d}{2m-1}$.

Thus the probability that a given couple survives is $p=\left(1-\frac{d}{2m}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{d}{2m-1}\right)$ and the mean number of surviving couples is $mp=m\cdot\left(1-\frac{d}{2m}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{d}{2m-1}\right)$.

Let $U_c$ denote the indicator function of the event that couple $c$ survives. The reasoning above identifies $p=E[U_c]$ as $p=\left(1-\frac{d}{2m}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{d}{2m-1}\right)$ for every $c$ and uses the fact that $X=\sum\limits_{c=1}^mU_c$ to deduce that $E[X]=mp$. Let us now adapt this approach to the computation of the second moment of $X$.

For two different couples $b\ne c$, $U_bU_c$ is the indicator function of the event that both couples $c$ and $b$ survive. This has probability $q=\left(1-\frac{d}{2m}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{d}{2m-1}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{d}{2m-2}\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{d}{2m-3}\right)$. Expanding the square $X^2$, one gets $m$ squares $U_c^2$, each such that $E[U_c^2]=E[U_c]=p$, and $m(m-1)$ products $U_cU_b$ with $b\ne c$, each such that $E[U_bU_c]=q$.

Hence $E[X^2]=mp+m(m-1)q$ and $\mathrm{var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=mp+m(m-1)q-m^2p^2$.